# Collection View Cell Width causes extra spacing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am creating a collection view with the same width as the view, and a set height. For the cells inside the collection view, I want there two be two columns, with each cell being half the width of the screen. I designed this in the storyboard on an iPhone 8, and it looks fine. When i view it on an iPhone 8 plus, there is some extra padding on the left of the right column as shown below.

[image: Extra padding on iPhone 8+]

I want to get rid of that padding. I've tried this by writing the code below, but it did not seem to work

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // Place content into hashtag cells
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "hashtagCell", for: indexPath) as! TrendingTagsCollectionViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.hashtagText = hashtags[indexPath.row]
        cell.frame.size.width = view.frame.width / 2
        return cell
}


extension GlobeTableViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing `collectionView(collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` in your delegate?

Comment: Yes, it still didn't change anything